# I can not open and edit any file dylib?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode, dylib

I tried and searched and did not find a solution for how to open the dylib file and modify it !

I have apps Plus iPhone example: WhatsApp++ Plus and Snapchat++ Plus ..etc and there is a file inside dylib and I want to open it and watch the source and modify it !

I'm sure I'll find your answer .

Comment: A ".dylib" file is a "dynamic shared library". It contains executable code, not source code.

Comment: Ok , Thanks , But How can I open and modify it?

Comment: What do you want to modify? The file contains (essentially) machine code for the ARM processor.

Comment: How do some developers edit the files of dylib and use them in applications like WhatsApp++ Plus and Instagram++ Plus SnapchatPHantom ... etc

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The library is machine code, so you can't modify "code" as we understand it. To do it you have to have the source code, modify it and compile it again

Comment: How do some developers edit the files of dylib and use them in applications like WhatsApp++ Plus and Instagram++ Plus SnapchatPHantom ... etc

Comment: I don't think they open and modify the library just how you want to do

Comment: I want to change some options and add a language or change the language within the application as an example snapchat++ https://server3.uaepro.me/files/18992/191655.ipa